# What does 50% certainty of a statement mean?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A friend of mine is visiting a family in the UK, which we visited together 3 month ago. As little present he wants to bring a wine but he can't remember if they like dry or sweet. So he asked me. I said, `"I'm 53% sure that they liked dry"`. Of course I wanted to express that I'm a little bit more confident that they like dry better than sweet.

He now objects that 0% confidence should mean that he doesn't gain any information from my statement (so it's 50/50 for him when he chooses the wine), while 100% means that he can just pick what I said and that will be correct.

However, what does `50% certainty of the statement "they liked dry"` (50% instead of 53% because that is easier here) mean for the probability that the kind of wine he chooses will be correct?

Is it 75%? Is it 66%? Is it something else or doesn't the statement make sense in the first place?

I thought it might be a conditional probability (something like `P(dry is correct | I said dry)`), but I do not come to a good solution...

Comment: The probability is $0.53$. What else ??

Comment: Personally I don't agree with your friend, if you  have two states, and you choose randomly (i.e. in an uninformed way) the probability of picking the right state is 0.5 (or 50% in percentage, although I am not familiar with this notation). If instead the probability of being right is 0 (0%) means that you are always wrong, which makes you a very "precise" forecaster.

Comment: Hi Databyte and welcome to MSE.  "The probability of $x$ is $50\%$" is subtly different to "I can say $x$ with $50\%$ certainty", although I don't think a precise definition of the difference currently exists in maths. As is always the case with maths, what that difference is, will depend on how, precisely, you define the meaning of "I can say $x$ with $50\%$ certainty.  One way I propose you define it is; $P(y)=.5$ and $y\implies x$. Then you have $p(x)\geq .5$, which I think is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in a mathematical sens your statement has no meaning.

Indeed in math you can say : $x%$ of a population satisfy this property. This is equivalent of saying if I peek randomly (uniformly) among among the population I have probability $x/$ of peeking something that satisfy the property.

For your statement the population is not defined it thus has no mathematical meaning.

However It is used in common language, and I would say that the usual meaning is the one you used. But since it is not well defined, your friend is not wrong either :)